# Swing, JavaFX, and Clojure aren't playing nice with the classpath

Tags: swing, javafx, clojure

Perhaps this is bug in Clojure... my question is...

Why when I create a new JLabel in the code below do I get a ClassNotFoundException while creating the JavaFX Stage but when I don't create the JLabel then the JavaFX Stage is created (and the class is found) just fine?

To reproduce this create a new leiningen project with `lein new app class-path-fail` and replace core.clj with this code:

```
(ns class-path-fail.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (javafx.stage Stage)
           (javafx.application Platform)
           (javax.swing JLabel SwingUtilities)
           (javafx.embed.swing JFXPanel)))

(JFXPanel.)

(SwingUtilities/invokeAndWait #(new JLabel "ha"))
(defn simple-fn-will-fail []
  (let [form `(fn [] (new Stage))]
    (eval form)))
(Platform/runLater #(simple-fn-will-fail))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

You can verify this doesn't work by running it... but then... comment out the creation of the JLabel and observe it works!!

I'm using Clojure 1.8.0.

Here's my project.clj:

```
(defproject class-path-fail "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot class-path-fail.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

I discovered that if the first two lines of code are reversed then Stage is found on the classpath and loaded. The new first two lines would look like:

```
(SwingUtilities/invokeAndWait #(new JLabel "ha"))
(JFXPanel.)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have run into similar issues (albeit in a different context), and I suspect it is due to the class loader configuration of the JavaFX application thread, not necessarily anything specific to Clojure. See for example this similar question: [API works with Java application but not JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668119/api-works-with-java-application-but-not-javafx) and: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2564617?start=0&tstart=0

That said, why are you using so many levels of indirection, and so many different mechanisms for scheduling things to happen in the future? The `eval` function is rarely needed in normal Clojure code.

The line `(Platform/runLater #(simple-fn-will-fail))` can be simplified: there is no need for the anonymous function, because `simple-fn-will-fail` is already a function taking no arguments. So this line is completely equivalent (and fails in exactly the same way): `(Platform/runLater simple-fn-will-fail)`

Also, `simple-fn-will-fail` does not actually try to create a new `Stage`, it just returns a function that will do that (and that function is discarded, never invoked), so if you were not invoking the compiler by calling `eval`, this problem would not occur.

If we can step back and get a better understanding of what you are actually trying to accomplish, there is probably a way to work around the issues with the class loader on the JavaFX application thread.

Anyway, those are some ideas. Perhaps we will hear more from someone with a deeper understanding of JavaFX and Clojure compilation.

I tinkered a bit more, after making my comment below, and found that even if I pulled the side-effecting forms inside `-main`, the same exception would be thrown trying to eval the form inside `simple-fn-will-fail`. So the issue was pointed all the more strongly at the JavaFX class loader.

I was able to get everything to run fine, however, by making sure that compilation occurs on the normal Clojure thread, and then running the resulting function (which, I think, is probably what you wanted to do anyway) using `Platform/runLater`. Here is my tweaked version:

```
(ns class-path-fail.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (javafx.stage Stage)
           (javafx.application Platform)
           (javax.swing JLabel SwingUtilities)
           (javafx.embed.swing JFXPanel)))

(defn simple-fn-will-fail []
  (let [form `(fn [] (new Stage))]
    (eval form)))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (JFXPanel.)
  (SwingUtilities/invokeAndWait #(new JLabel "ha"))
  (let [stage-creator (simple-fn-will-fail)]
    (Platform/runLater stage-creator))

  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

With this version, I can invoke `(-main)` with no problem.

Comment: It is also generally a bad idea to run code with side effects at the time your namespace is being compiled and loaded (in particular, calling `SwingUtilities/invokeAndWait` at the top level like you do raises all kinds of red flags in my head--that is going to pause the compilation and loading of your namespace until Swing has a chance to load, and pump that function invocation through its event queue; goodness knows what kinds of race conditions and unexpected states that can lead to).

Comment: Please update your answer to clearly and concisely answer the question. Please remove suggestions to improve the code that do not actually answer the question.

Comment: If you think that’s possible, I’d greatly appreciate seeing how. As it stands, the question is trying to do too much, in ways that lead to incredibly complex issues that are fundamentally unnecessary. So I am trying to help simplify the situation and help the original poster achieve their underlying goals.

Comment: I am the original poster. I spent quite some time distilling out the actual problem from the code, which is not all my code. This problem occurred outside my code because of a combination of libraries I was using and I couldn't figure out why things stopped working. I finally isolated the problem and created the simplest example I could to demonstrate the problem... and I cannot change the code in these libraries! I could submit a patch, but a patch wouldn't resolve the order problem since one library uses JavaFX and the other Swing. I want to migrate to JavaFX, but I cannot do so overnight.

Comment: I see! And I take it you are unable to share the source in its actual context? Because of the complex interactions involved here between class paths, threading, and the compiler, it may not be practical to discuss or resolve with an isolated example like this. I stand by my concerns and recommendations; if the libraries you’re using do things like calling SwingUtilities/invokeandWait at the top level, when compiled, they should be fixed to not do that, or abandoned. If you can find a way to make sure that compilation happens (including via eval) on the proper thread, you should be ok.